Conceptually bridging the gap between the classical and quantum harmonic oscillator in the context of phonons
Background: The harmonic oscillator can be treated classically and quantumly.
Classically, the harmonic oscillator consists of a mass under a restoring force $F = m\ddot{x} = -kx$ where the equation of motion goes like $x(t) = A\text{cos}(\omega t)$ where $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$. In this picture, harmonic oscillators are things that oscillate sinusoidally.
In treating the quantum harmonic oscillator, we find that the oscillator is characterized by its excitation modes. The spectrum of the harmonic oscillator is evenly spaced energy values $E_n = (n + \frac{1}{2})\hbar \omega$. So in this case, we can imagine the oscillator is a thing that is characterized by its modes of excitation.
Now, I am specifically looking at this in the context of phonons. In my condensed matter course, we initially realize that there should be some scattering mechanism in crystals. We go about finding this mechanism by first treating the classical harmonic crystal where we imagine that ion cores in a lattice have non negligible movements. We imagine these ions oscillate and calculate the dispersion relation much in the same way we would for masses on a spring in classical mechanics. We also treat this situation quantum mechanically and discover that the modes of excitation of the ion cores are phonons.
Question: This brings me to my question how can I conceptualize phonon scattering in a way that unites the classical and quantum mechanical descriptions of ion cores? I see the idea that the ion cores have motion. This contributes to the energy and, thus, the specific heat capacity. However, when I try to imagine the scattering mechanism, I am unsure what it means to scatter off of modes. I can picture the classical oscillations of the ions in the crystal, but I fail when trying to unite this with the quantum mechanical picture of the lattice.

Since I prefer - wherever possible - the classical concept (i.e. without hidden variables or uncertainties), I can only go half way with you.
TL;DR
The model of the harmonic quantum oscillator can be mechanically reconstructed as follows:

take a rotating wheel and place it between two walls
the kinetic energy should be just large enough for the wheel to overcome the standstill point (highest point of the ellipse)
the elliptical wheel should be placed so skillfully that it reaches the first wall with the greatest speed (potential energy zero, kinetic max).
the wall should be massive and perfectly elastic, reversing the direction of motion of the wheel - the wall should be placed at a distance that corresponds to a multiple of half the diameter of the ellipse

This model can be extended to model the oscillation of photons. This requires the following extension of the model:

instead of a wheel, a double ellipsoidal body (ellipse in X and in Y) is used
the second ellipse corresponds to the wall like a spring; the ellipsoid compresses the wall and springs back again
the wall is anisotropic, elastic in one direction and springy in the other.

This allows you to model the harmonic oscillator for both the electric and magnetic field components of the photon. On the double ellipsoid you can now write N and S (in X, for example) and + and- (then in Y).
BTW, in such a model you can also arrange the walls with a quarter offset. One wall then reflects with the E-field, the other with the B-field.
TL;DR
In a crystal, just as in any solid body, there are two phenomena when energy is introduced from outside

a longitudinal wave in which the applied energy propagates in the direction of impact
a transverse wave, which is the dissipative part of the impact.

In the case of a full-surface impact on one side of the body/crystal, the dissipative part is only noticeable on the lateral surfaces. Within the body, the shear forces compensate each other.
So if I look at the kinetically excited atoms in a crystal, the mechanistic model assumes springy connections between neighboring atoms. The longitudinal springing back and forth in Z is supplemented by transverse tensions in X and Y.
All this is well known for mechanical impacts and sound effects. And it also applies to the introduction of energy by means of heat. And also for EM waves. It even applies to the effect of a photon - useful for high-energy photons, as otherwise the dissipative part has the upper hand and only a skin effect is visible.

Relativisticcucumber: how can I conceptualize phonon scattering in a way that unites the classical and quantum mechanical descriptions of ion cores?

Now it is up to you to connect the following description of the phonon with the above and to analyze which situations and advantages there are of the quantum mechanical approach compared to the mechanistic one.

A phonon is a collective excitation in a periodic, elastic arrangement of atoms or molecules in condensed matter, specifically in solids and some liquids. A type of quasiparticle in physics, a phonon is an excited state in the quantum mechanical quantization of the modes of vibrations for elastic structures of interacting particles. Phonons can be thought of as quantized sound waves, similar to photons as quantized light waves.

Note: The difference between the mechanistic model and the quantum mechanical model lies in the anisotropy of the latter. This is necessary in order to take into account the electric and magnetic field components of the subatomic particles and the photon involved. The model described above takes both field components into account and should therefore be adequate to the model introduced by Tamm and Frenkel.
